# How to allow R shiny to read .xlsx and csv files without conflicts?

Tags: r

I am trying to allow users to upload .xlsx and csv files but always get errors.

```
 ui:
fileInput(
              inputId = "file",
              label = "",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c("text/csv",".xlsx",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv",
                         '.xlsx'),
              placeholder = "Use Ctrl key to choose files"
            ))



Server:

    read.csv(input$file$datapath) -Here, how to deal with .xlsx files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't use `read.csv` to read Excel files, they are not CSV files.
Try `read_excel` from {[readxl](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/)}.

So you can do things like, if it is csv you use `read.csv`, if it is `xlsx`, use `readxl`

You didn't provide the full code, so here I can just give you some snippets:

```r
if(stringr::str_ends(input$file$datapath, "csv")) {
    read.csv(input$file$datapath)
} else if (stringr::str_ends(input$file$datapath, "(xlsx|xls)")) {
    readxl::read_excel(input$file$datapath)
}
```

Comment: There is an error. Error in read_fun: function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'...incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpchBsBP/d99e3129c7612d3beca65fea/0.xlsx'

Comment: I already installed the package "readxl" but xlsx files cannot be read.

Comment: Maybe you have more than 1 sheet or other reasons. Please refer to the readxl manual. xlsx files are different case by case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  inFile <- input$file
  extension <- tools::file_ext(inFile$name)
  filepath <- inFile$datapath
  df <- switch(extension,
               csv = readr::read_csv(filepath),
               xls = readxl::read_xls(filepath),
               xlsx = readxl::read_xlsx(filepath)
```